# Set cover problem with constant 2

Tags: computational-complexity

I have a question about the Set Cover problem:
If I get a universe U, m subsets that the size of each subset is exactly 2, and an integer k.
Is this problem is still NP-C or I can solve it on a polynomial time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The SET COVER problem with all sets having size 2 is equivalent to the [EDGE COVER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover) problem (each element in $U$ becomes a vertex in the graph, and each subset becomes an edge).

EDGE COVER can be solved in polynomial time by constructing a [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs) (for example, using [Edmond's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)) and then extending the matching to cover all the vertices.